# Using optparse or argparse to process multiple arguments using the same option

Tags: python, argparse, optparse

I'm trying to write a python script that can echo whatever a user types when running the script

Right now, the code I have is (version_msg and usage_msg don't matter right now)

```
from optparse import OptionParser 

version_msg = ""
usage_msg = ""
parser = OptionParser(version=version_msg, usage=usage_msg)
parser.add_option("-e", "--echo", action="append", dest="input_lines", default=[])
```

But if I try to run the script (python options.py -e hello world), it echoes just ['hello']. How would I go about fixing this so it outputs ['hello', 'world']?

Comment: Please provide the complete code showing the values of version_msg and usage_msg

Comment: @ShivamSingh fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly hacky way of doing it:

```
from optparse import OptionParser

version_msg = ""
usage_msg = ""
parser = OptionParser(version=version_msg, usage=usage_msg)
parser.add_option("-e", "--echo", action="append", dest="input_lines", default=[])

options, arguments = parser.parse_args()

print(options.input_lines + arguments)
```

I then run

```
python myscript.py -e hello world how are you
```

Output:

```
['hello', 'world', 'how', 'are', 'you']
```

Comment: So you are collecting `hello` as an argument to `-e`, and everything else as the extras, the `arguments`.  From an `argparse` perspective, that isn't very satisfying.

Comment: Collecting a variable number of arguments is a bit more involved in `optparse` than in `argparse`.

Answer (score 2):

In `argparse` this is quite easy, with its `nargs` parameter:

```
In [245]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [246]: parser.add_argument('-e','--echo', nargs='+');
In [247]: parser.parse_args(['-e','hello','world'])
Out[247]: Namespace(echo=['hello', 'world'])
```

`nargs` is used to specify how many strings the Action takes.  '+' means one or more.  The results are collected in a list.  It models the `nargs` values on the regex usage (e.g. '?' and '*' also work).

```
In [248]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-e ECHO [ECHO ...]]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -e ECHO [ECHO ...], --echo ECHO [ECHO ...]
```

---

Looking at the `optparse` docs, I see a `nargs` parameter, but it must be a number.  For a variable number, we have to use a `callback` as described in:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#callback-example-6-variable-arguments

Using the function defined in this section:

```
In [266]: parser = optparse.OptionParser()
In [267]: parser.add_option('-e','--echo', dest='echo', action='callback', callback=vararg_callback);

In [268]: parser.parse_args(['-e','hello','world'])
Out[268]: (<Values at 0x7f0ff208a5c0: {'echo': ['hello', 'world']}>, [])
```

In `argparse`, `nargs='+'` collects values up to the next `--` or `-`, but that allocation is done topdown, by the main parsing routine, not a callback defined for the `option` itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is best accomplished by quoting the argument ie hello world becomes 'hello world' this ensures that the -e option consumes the entire string. 
If you really need the string to be broken up into pieces ie ['hello', 'world'] instead of ['hello world'] you could easily call split() on options.e[0]

```
strings = options.e[0].split()
```

For a more complex method, you can use a callback, below links to a relevant example for you.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/optparse.html#callback-example-6-variable-arguments

Comment: Hmm that looks almost what I want, but it just stores Hello World as a single element in the list rather than 2 distinct elements